# How to create two layered MbTiles for large featured files using Tippecanoe?

Tags: geojson, mbtiles, tippecanoe, tileserver-gl, react-mapbox-gl

My requirement is to process 3+ millions of geojson data(Polygon feature) and visualize it on Map in a way that it should show Polygons on the highest zoom level(individual entity) and clusters(in form of bubbles/circles may be) on the lower zoom levels(aggregated based on radius)

Right now I convert the polygon feature geojson to point feature geojson (because I didn't find a way to create mbtiles on polygon file using Tippecanoe) and then I create 2 separate MbTiles using Tippecanoe for both the levels and pass this to tileserver-gl to facilitate the tiles to the front(using react-mapbox-gl for front end) but this takes a lot of time and the mbtiles is also huge. Geojson files used for clusters(point geojson) is 1.2 GB and polygons is 4.3 GB and the resulting mbtiles are ~520 MB and ~4.3 GB respectively and I join them to create a combined mbtiles which is equally huge.

In future I will need to create multiple mbtiles on various geojson files and creating a separate Point geojson every time and also the time required to calculate the mbtiles will be too much.

Is there any other library which takes lesser time and gives the same behaviour with Polygon geojson or if there is a workaround with Tippecanoe.

Following are the commands I am using:

1. To create point mbtiles(for zoom 0 level through 15 )

- tippecanoe -z15 -o points.mbtiles -r1 --cluster-distance=50 --coalesce-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping points.geojson

2. To create polygon mbtiles(for zoom above 16 level)

- tippecanoe -zg -Z16 -o polygons.mbtiles --coalesce-densest-as-needed --extend-zooms-if-still-dropping polygons.geojson

3. To merge both the mbtiles

- tile-join -o point-polygon.mbtiles points.mbtiles polygons.mbtiles

4. Tile server

- tileserver-gl point-polygon.mbtiles